# systemProperties in an external file?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, properties, automation

I have just started with Maven today so am still getting up to speed. I have set up a selenium test in Eclipse, in my test I have `baseUrl = System.getProperty("webdriver.base.url");`

I then run the test via command line passing in the argument I want the base url to be

`mvn clean test -Dwebdriver.base.url=http://www.google.com`

My problem is that I am working on a test where I will need to pass in a lot of arguments and would prefer if I could read them from a properties file instead of having a massive command line argument.

Is this possible and can anyone point me to a tutorial so I can set this up?

I have read about the mojo properties maven plugin which I have added to my `pom.xml` but I haven't been able to get it working so far.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question - are you trying to read the properties from your Java code OR are you trying to have Maven set the properties when running your tests (i.e. by automating the `-Dprop=val` across a wide set of properties)?

Answer (score 1):

put the properties file in `src/test/resources` from test class read it as resource

```
InputStream in = YourTestClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("some.properties");
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(in);
// access key values
properties.getProperty("someKey")
```

Note: this doesn't handle exceptions, You need to do it on your own

Comment: Sorry I missed out some important information! The reason I need (or think I need) to pass the properties file on the Maven command line is because I will be running a set of Selenium tests on different sites so I will have a properties file for each site.

Comment: So pass a single param that will identify the unique properties file for that site